# Can the Drawer be permanent and lay over the content?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, navigation-drawer, material-ui

I want a mini drawer on the left of my screen, like the example on the [Material UI Documentation](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/#mini-variant-drawer):

[image]

But in my case I want it to float over the content (like the `variant="temporary"` version of the component) when it opens, as currently it pushes the content.

If I handle the `open` prop to change the variant style dynamically it doesn't look very nice.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the content's styling like this, it's position will not be effected by the drawer's state as you set its position to be absolute:

```
content: {
    position: "absolute",
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 7 + 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  }
```

The Header text will ofcourse shift to the left when you open the drawer.

EDIT: I am going off of the codesanbox [Material UI demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7joy724pl) for the mini variant drawer here.